# User Resources for REST API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, api, devise

I am using the `devise` gem for `rails`.

The default routes generated for users include some of the following routes:

```
    new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                                            devise/passwords#new
   edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                                                           devise/passwords#edit
        user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                      PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                      POST   /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#create
```

I'm trying to understand why they didn't use `/users/:id/password`, etc.?

For example, I'm adding a user `preference` route. I can follow the same logic and make something like `/users/preferences` but it feels like it should be `/users/:id/preferences` based on the currently logged in users. However, I'm trying to keep everything similar and `devise` already set the precedent unless I change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* do `/users/:id/preferences`. But, `params[:user_id]` will (presumably) equal `current_user.id`. So, it's a bit redundant.

Instead, you can just do `/users/preferences` and access the relevant `id` from `current_user`. (Which, if you like this sort of thing, obscures the current user's id by not including it in the url.)

Comment: So basically the rule of thumb is that if you don't need to expose a page to the outside world and the only way for users to access a route is by being currently logged in then there's no need to use the id? Is this good design as far as REST standards?

Comment: Your rule of thumb seems reasonable given your described context. As far as REST standards, I'm no expert. But, it seems to me that you are still using the standard HTTP verbs to access the `preferences` resources, so I would think that it's A-OK.

Comment: To avoid an eventual confusion you use `/current_user/` instead of `/users/`